# Where can I find SQL keywords constants in Java, for example "DESC"?

Tags: java, android, sql

I have sort criteria that looks the following:

```
MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_ADDED + " DESC"
```

I'd like to replace the `DESC` with some constant.

**Another option would be to use a statement builder**. Anyone knows of such?

Comment: Maybe it's better to use an ORM.

Comment: @m0skit0 - not in Android. The queries are short anyhow. Anyhow, still looking for a way to create the short sort statement above without concatenating strings.

Comment: These aren't called constants, they're called `keywords` (just like `int` is a keyword in C/C++/Java).  You can look them up in your db provider's docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd like to replace the DESC with some constant.

Why. It *is* a constant, from the SQL language point of view. Nobody is going to change it. From the Java point of view, it's a pooled String literal.

Java doesn't provide keywords of other languages as constants. It would be a Sisyohean task.

Don't worry about it.

Comment: Then what about some kind of a statement builder?

Comment: What about it? There isn"t one in Java. Feel free. Or see Hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the constant yourself!

```
public static class RedundantConstantDeclarations
{
    public static final String THE_STRING_DESC_AS_FREAKING_ITSELF = " DESC";
}

//...

MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_ADDED + RedundantConstantDeclarations.THE_STRING_DESC_AS_FREAKING_ITSELF
```

Or...

You could simply use `" DESC"` directly, assuming that if you even have to migrate to a SQL dialect alien enough to replace the keyword `DESC`, a one-to-one keyword mapping won't be enough and you'll have to rewrite the queries anyways.